# How do I write a regex that checks that a binary operator isn't immediately followed by another binary operator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a web calculator. The calculator is able to evaluate expressions such as `1*(2-5)`.

I want to write a regular expression that checks that each binary operator isn't immediately followed by another binary operator (binary operators supported in the calculator: `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `^`).

For example, `1*(2-5)` is a correct expression, and `1/*(2-5)` is an incorrect expression.

I have written several versions of a regexp with positive and negative lookahead assertions:

1. `/[+\-/*^](?=[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[(])/g` (positive lookahead)
2. `/[+\-/*^](?![+\-/*^])/g` (negative lookahead)

I tested the 1st regex against this string `1/*(2-5)` and it works. But when I test it against the correct string `1*(2-5)` the behavior becomes strange. It passes the check two times of three and every third time it fails. I mean, I enter this expression into my calculator, click `=` button and it validates it. Two times the expression passes the validation and one time doesn't. Passes -> passes -> doesn't pass -> passes -> passes -> doesn't pass.

What is wrong with my regular expression? Or is it some sort of bug? (the project is built using JavaScript and I wrap every regular expression into `new RegExp(...)`).

Comment: Easy, as always in these cases, remove the `g` flag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but in this case only the first occurrence of a binary operator will be checked. I need to check every binary operator. Am I wrong?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I changed the regexp to `/[+\-/*^](?=[+\-/*^])/` and just updated logic of the validation. Now, the method for validating this case checks that "binary operator are not followed by incorrect characters" instead of "binary operators are followed by valid characters". And once the invalid pattern is found, the expression returns false. And it works now. Thanks!